# How to JOIN 2 tables into one query using fields in third table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to solve task for last hours...

I have four tables:

```
Users (ID INT, Fullname VARCHAR(255))

Segments (Value VARCHAR(255))

Report_1 (ID INT, UserID INT, Segment VARCHAR(255), Total INT)

Report_2 (ID INT, UserID INT, Segment VARCHAR(255), Total INT)
```

...and I need to get reports by all users with all possible segments.

But reports from "Report_1", "Report_2" may not have records for some users or segments.

The result query must have this columns:

```
UserID, Segment, Report_1.Total(OR NULL), Report_2.Total(OR NULL)
```

Could I use CROSS JOIN / APPLY or something?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Now I know it... and absolutely agree! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple cartesian join with an outer join should do the trick:

```
SELECT Users.ID AS [UserID], Segments.Value AS [Segment], Report_1.Total, Report_2.Total
FROM Users, Segments
LEFT OUTER JOIN Report_1 ON 
    Report_1.UserID = Users.ID AND Report_1.Segment = Segments.Value
LEFT OUTER JOIN Report_2 ON 
    Report_2.UserID = Users.ID AND Report_2.Segment = Segments.Value
```

Comment: I have an error on **SQL Server 2012** for real-world query. 
So I forced to use: **FROM Users CROSS JOIN Segments**

instead of commas...

Answer (score 0):

Best that I can suggest is:

```sql
SELECT
    U.UserID,
    S.Value,
    ISNULL(R1.Total, 0),
    ISNULL(R2.Total, 0)
FROM
    Users U
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM Segment
) S
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM(Total) AS Total,
        Segment,
        UserID
    FROM
        Report_1
    GROUP BY
        Segment,
        UserID
) R1 ON
    R1.UserID = U.UserID AND
    R1.Segment = S.Value
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        SUM(Total) AS Total,
        Segment,
        UserID
    FROM
        Report_2
    GROUP BY
        Segment,
        UserID
) R2 ON
    R2.UserID = U.UserID AND
    R2.Segment = S.Value
```

I hope that is good usage for **CROSS APPLY**...